# NullPointerException Caused by getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I have tried hell lot of things but my  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); is throwing null

I also saw relative post on stack overflow bt its not resolving my problem
I am using min SDK = 16 and trying to jump from Mainactivity fragment to detail activity fragment
My intent is working fine but in my detail activity toolbar and back button is missing.
My main activity where i call the intent to jmp to detail activity
inside setOnitemlistener method

```
package com.example.android.sunshine;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.Log;    
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
* A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
*/
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {
String LOG_TAG = MainActivityFragment.class.getSimpleName();
ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menuitem,menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == R.id.action_refresh){
        FetchWeatherTask fetchWeatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();

fetchWeatherTask.execute("Mathura","402c19fed0e53f9d92a81107ec2f6c2f");
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, 
false);
    String[] forecastArray = {
            "Sun May 1-CLEAR-31/17",
            "Mon May 1-CLEAR-31/17",
            "Tue May 1-CLEAR-31/17",
            "Wed May 1-CLEAR-31/17",
            "Thu May 1-CLEAR-31/17",
            "Fri May 1-CLEAR-31/17",
            "Sat May 1-CLEAR-31/17"
    };
    List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>
(Arrays.asList(forecastArray));
    mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
(getActivity()
,R.layout.listitemforecast,
R.id.listitemforecastText,
weekForecast
);
    ListView listView = 
(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_textView);
    listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
position, long id) {
            String forecast = mForecastAdapter.getItem(position);
           // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),forecast, 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),DetailActivity.class)
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,forecast);
            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,"error: "+ e);
            }
        }
    });
return rootView;
}


public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String[]> {

    /* The date/time conversion code is going to be moved outside the 
asynctask later,
    * so for convenience we're breaking it out into its own method now.
    */
    private String getReadableDateString(long time){
        // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
        // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to 
valid date.
        SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE 
MMM dd");
        return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
     */
    private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
        // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a 
degree.
        long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
        long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

        String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
        return highLowStr;
    }

    /**
     * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format 
and
     * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the 
wireframes.
     *
     * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and 
converts it
     * into an Object hierarchy for us.
     */
    private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int 
numDays)
            throws JSONException {

        // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be 
extracted.
        final String OWM_LIST = "list";
        final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
       // final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
        final String OWM_MAX = "temp_max";
        final String OWM_MIN = "temp_min";
        final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

        JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
        JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

        // OWM returns daily forecasts based upon the local time of the 
city that is being
        // asked for, which means that we need to know the GMT offset to 
translate this data
        // properly.

        // Since this data is also sent in-order and the first day is 
always the
        // current day, we're going to take advantage of that to get a nice
        // normalized UTC date for all of our weather.

        Time dayTime = new Time();
        dayTime.setToNow();

        // we start at the day returned by local time. Otherwise this is a 
mess.
        int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), 
dayTime.gmtoff);

        // now we work exclusively in UTC
        dayTime = new Time();

        String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
        for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
            // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
            String day;
            String description;
            String highAndLow;

            // Get the JSON object representing the day
            JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

            // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert 
that
            // into something human-readable, since most people won't read 
"1400356800" as
            // "this saturday".
            long dateTime;
            // Cheating to convert this to UTC time, which is what we want 
anyhow
            dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);
            day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

            // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 
element long.
            JSONObject weatherObject = 
dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
            description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

            // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not 
to name variables
            // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses 
everybody.
            JSONObject temperatureObject = 
dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_DESCRIPTION);
            double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
            double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

            highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
            resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
        }

        return resultStrs;
    }


        protected void onPostExecute(String[] Results){
            mForecastAdapter.clear();
            for(String day: Results){
                mForecastAdapter.add(day);
            }
        }







    protected String[] doInBackground(String... Params){

        String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();
        // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
// so that they can be closed in the finally block.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

// Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String forecastJsonStr = null;
        String format = "json";
        String units = "metric";
        int NumDays = 7;
        try {
            String Place = "q";
            String Mode = "mode";
            String cnt = "cnt";
            String Units = "units";
            String Appid = "APPID";
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, 
at
            // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
            final String ForecastBaseURL = 
"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?";
            Uri builturi = Uri.parse(ForecastBaseURL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(Place,Params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter(Mode,format)
                    .appendQueryParameter(cnt,Integer.toString(NumDays))
                    .appendQueryParameter(Units,units)
                    .appendQueryParameter(Appid,Params[1]).build();
            URL url = new URL(builturi.toString());
           // Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Built URI:"+builturi.toString());
            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the 
connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it 
won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print 
out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                forecastJsonStr = null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data,  
there's no point in attemping
            // to parse it.
            forecastJsonStr = null;
        } finally{
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        try{
            return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr,NumDays);
        }catch (JSONException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"json error" + e);
        }

     return null;
    }
}
}
```

My detail activity:

```
package com.example.android.sunshine;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DetailActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    if(getActionBar() != null){
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);  // Here its 
throwing null
    }
}

}
```

My detail fragment.java

```
package com.example.android.sunshine;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

 /**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class  DetailActivityFragment extends Fragment {

public DetailActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, 
false);
    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    if(intent != null && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT))
    {
        String forecast = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        ((TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.detail_text))
                .setText(forecast);

    }

    return rootview;
}
}
```

My Main activity:

```
package com.example.android.sunshine;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) 
findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is 
present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

My Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.sunshine">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/sunshine"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.android.sunshine.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

As in you AndroidManifest.xml, your activity use a theme that has no actionbar:
    
    `<activity
        android:name=".DetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.android.sunshine.MainActivity" />
    </activity>`

So, you can change you theme to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

your DetailActivity should extends AppCompatActivity

```
package com.example.android.sunshine;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    if(getActionBar() != null){
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);  
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part of the code in your DetailActivtity

```
if(getActionBar() != null){
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);  
}
```

And implement this method after your onCreate Method, your back button will come up and start working.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend **AppCompatActivity**,Detail **activity**

```
package com.example.android.sunshine; 

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

} 

}
```

And also check your style file

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="AppTheme">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```